# Is it grammatical to use "in" here? "He is proficient in acting."

Tags: prepositions

"He is proficient in acting."

I think "at" works here, but since acting is an area, I feel that it's correct to use "in". Am I right?

Comment: To be proficient in a language, to be proficient at a thing, like acting. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

With your specific example of acting - it all depends on whether you are using 'acting' as the name of a *skill*, or a *field of employment*. If it is a skill, then you'd say "proficient *at* acting". If it refers to the field, then use 'in'.

When it comes to skills and jobs, you'll find a number of prepositions used, depending on the context.

We tend to use "at" when referring to the *place* we work:

**Example:** I work at the bank.

We use "in" when referring to the 'field' we work in (ie the *type* of work):

**Example:** I work in engineering.

We can also use "with" to describe the kind of work we do:

**Example:** I work with children.

There are other variations too - for example, a farmer works *on* a farm. Likewise, there are some skills we may say we are proficient *in*, such as speaking languages.